# Mysql Workbench crashes at startup on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, crash, mysql-workbench

I've got installed Mysql-Workbench (version 5.2.35) for data modeling on my Ubuntu 11.10 but, when i run

```
mysql-workbench
```

it crashes with this error message:

```
 ** Message: Gnome keyring daemon seems to not be available. Stored passwords will be lost
    once quit
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

---

**SOLVED** (but don't ask me why ... )

I've got closed the mysql-workbench splash screen and (WOW!) , after i've closed this splash, mysql-workbench starts.

Comment: What happens if you run `mysql` from the command line?  Is it able to connect to a server?

Comment: yes it is. I'm able to connect to mysql-server.

Comment: i've tried to launch workbench with root privileges but nothing happens ...

Comment: It must be a bug of Workbench. It seems not to be able to continue after splash screens and dialogs are up. You shouldn't need to run an application with root privileges anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's a very strange Bug and the Error Message doesn't seems consistent....  :-(